# Can I set region width with python?

Tags: python, panel

I can get TOLLS width with code:

```
for region in bpy.context.area.regions:
    if region.type == "TOOLS":
        print(region.width)
        break
```

I can't set it in the same way (read-only error).
Is it possible to set it by python script?

Comment: Not easy to find an answer! Same questions here.